# .babylon js file camera rotation

Tags: babylonjs

just started with babylonJS and got a .fbx file exported from Blender to .babylon.

Am using `BABYLON.SceneLoader.Load` to get my object.

The camera is rotation around its axis and instead I would like it to rotate around the object.

Playground: http://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#JR2HVU
don't know how to use an external file for the car, but I hope you guys can at least look at the code and maybe spot something i'm doing wrong.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got on answer on the **html5gamedevs** so I thought of sharing it here.

the problem was the use of a `freecamera` instead of an `ArcRotateCamera` and also creating a new camera inside the `SceneLoader`.

I'll leave a link to the full answer and playground links here:
http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/34191-babylon-file-camera-rotation/